# Open source Android automation (alternative to Tasker, Macrodroid)

Tags: android, open-source, automation

I want to set up a few very simple "automations" on my Android device:

Required triggers:

- Buttons on the home screen
- At startup
- ... and the more the better

Required actions:

- Set up notification level of a particular app, for instance normal or muted
- Create a new custom notification

I want an open source app, so not Tasker or MacroDroid.

Comment: There is on on F-Droid called [Easer](https://f-droid.org/en/packages/ryey.easer/)  - but to be honest I did not understand how to make it work. I find it utterly complicated, but maybe that's just me.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: I have actually used Easer already. Buttons on the homescreen can easily be added as widget with a tag that you then reference in a new `Event` (in `Data`). A profile is a set of operations. A script links an event to a profile. Problem is, no operation seem to be available to mute/allow notifications... I just created a feature request for this: https://github.com/renyuneyun/Easer/issues/316